# Individuals and properties in semantic web

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, owl, ontology

I'm currently working on a semantic web e-learning project. I've made an ontology and classes. However, when populating RDF files, I create an individual (for example a course) and place it in a RDF. Afterwards if I it is needed to relate another individual to this one by an object property (e.g. student-> studyMemberOf-> course), I put course Uri in student individual. This means (course individual Uri: crs000021):

```
<Ontologyowl:Student rdf:about="ehsanm">
    <Ontologyowl:studyMemberOf>
        <Ontologyowl:Project rdf:about="crs000021"/>
    </Ontologyowl:studyMemberOf>
```

I have **2 Questions** here:
 
Is it right to put individuals of each class, in a separate RDF file?
When relating these two individuals, am I making another node of 'course (crs000021)' in student file? is this method (making different rdfs) incorrect?

Thank you for your attention

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no specification about how and where you should write your RDF statement. You can write all the statements in the same file or each statement in one file.
Moreover a RDF store should ignore every duplicated statements, so

```
<ehsanm> <studyMemberOf> <crs000021>
<crs000021> rdf:type  Ontologyowl:Project
<student2> <studyMemberOf> <crs000021>
<crs000021> rdf:type  Ontologyowl:Project
```

is the same as

```
<ehsanm> <studyMemberOf> <crs000021>
<crs000021> rdf:type  Ontologyowl:Project
<student2> <studyMemberOf> <crs000021>
```

Note: I'm not sure  rdf:about="ehsanm" is a valid URI. I guess you should use rdf:ID here

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. About the note, do you mean it should be rdf:<valid Uri>? Thank you again for your helpful effort

Comment: To be clear, the reason one assertion of `<crs000021> rdf:type  Ontologyowl:Project` is "removed" is that both are assertions of the exact same statement, which is redundant. This is much of the utility of the semantic web because you are using URIs as sort of "foreign key" between RDF documents (graphs).